# slack slash commands show response only to channel

Tags: slack-api, slack

slack provides only two types of responses:

- ephemeral = make the command and response shown to the user only.
- in_channel = make the command and response shown to all users in channel.

#### ephemeral example:

[image: ephemeral response]

#### in_channel example:

[image: in_channel response]

## Question:

#### how can i make a slash command show response ***only*** in channel and not show both command and response?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ok so i found my question's answer, it is said in slack's api that

> The only user-facing difference between immediate responses and delayed responses is that "in channel" delayed responses will not include the initial command sent by the user. To echo the command back to the channel, you'll still need to provide a response to Slack's original visit to your invocation URL.

reference https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_to_a_command

Comment: did you end up finding a way to implement delayed response?

Comment: @user2891681yes! go to the url, it says it all

Comment: Has anyone found a solution?