# Slack API - remotely delete slash command message from channel

Tags: slack-api

I have a slash command set up in Slack to go look up some info and post a response message back to the channel. I would like the original slash command message that the user sent ("/whatever go get stuff") to be "replaced" by the response message, so effectively I want to delete the slash command message so the user only sees the response in the channel (similar to how /giphy command works).

My slash command works fine, but I can't figure out how to easily delete the message that triggered the command. I was looking into using the [api/chat.delete](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete) endpoint, but I don't have enough info to form the POST data because the slash command request doesn't include `ts`.

Does anyone have an idea about how to get rid of that last message?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I found my answer by rephrasing the question - use the `response_url` to deliver your response 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682927/slack-slash-commands-show-response-only-to-channel/35700375

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete interactive message (command response) just with Slack Commands API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627080/delete-interactive-message-command-response-just-with-slack-commands-api)